# how to add seperate meta tags for each page using header.php page on wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, meta-tags

I want to add the separate meta tags for the each page using the header.php

To add the **title**,**Meta Description**,**Meta Keywords** of the every page
for better SEO Anlayis. I want achieve this through code on header.php page.

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />-->

<style>
/*.alignleft { left:0px !important;}
*/
</style>

<title>
<?php
    /*
     * Print the <title> tag based on what is being viewed.
     */
    global $page, $paged;
    wp_title( '|', true, 'right' );
    // Add the blog name.
    bloginfo( 'blogname' );
    // Add the blog description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) )
        echo " | $site_description";
    // Add a page number if necessary:
    if ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 )
        echo ' | ' . sprintf( __( 'Page %s'), max( $paged, $page ) );
?>
</title>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, where's the problem?

Comment: I want to add the meta description  and meta keywords of the each for better search results of the webpage without using any SEO Plungins.For giving the unique description and keywords,title of each page. in  my code it is adding the title of the page but i also want description and keywords of each page. Is there any solution to achieve this?

Comment: you can use `is_page( 'Page_ID' )` as condition state to to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is use a hook using condition.

Simply use this code to your `functions.php` but change **english** `is_page('english')` to your `page_ID` or `slug` or `title`

```
function add_meta_data_firefog() {

    if ( is_page('english') ) {
        echo'<meta name="Keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3,Keyword4,Keyword5,Keyword6">';
        echo'<meta name="Description" content="Your Description">';
    }
    if ( is_page('aboutus') ) {
        echo'<meta name="Keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3,Keyword4,Keyword5,Keyword6">';
        echo'<meta name="Description" content="Your Description">';
    }
    if ( is_page('newspaper') ) {
        echo'<meta name="Keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3,Keyword4,Keyword5,Keyword6">';
        echo'<meta name="Description" content="Your Description">';
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_data_firefog');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi can i do this with the nromal phpo website?
function add_meta_data_firefog() {

```
if ( is_page('english') ) {
    echo'<meta name="Keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3,Keyword4,Keyword5,Keyword6">';
    echo'<meta name="Description" content="Your Description">';
}
if ( is_page('aboutus') ) {
    echo'<meta name="Keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3,Keyword4,Keyword5,Keyword6">';
    echo'<meta name="Description" content="Your Description">';
}
if ( is_page('newspaper') ) {
    echo'<meta name="Keywords" content="Keyword1,Keyword2,Keyword3,Keyword4,Keyword5,Keyword6">';
    echo'<meta name="Description" content="Your Description">';
}
```

}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_meta_data_firefog');